# Highcharts: how to change "overscroll" parameter on "afterSetExtremes" even?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a `highchart` and I need it's `overscroll` to have the value: the half of the visible range in X axis.
So when zoom level changes, this `overscroll` value should change with it.
I created an example in the following jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/vgL5kd37/

Where I have already calculated the value which needs to be set for the `overscroll` and I'm only missing the way this value should be set.
Since the initial zoom level (range) is set to 1m, the initial `overscroll` will have half of the milliseconds in one minute `(1 * 60 * 1000 / 2)`.

Assuming that the calculations and the update needs to happen on `afterSetExtremes` event (when extremes on the X axis changes), I have added a method that calculates the value of the new `overscroll` and this value is displayed in an alert box.

I'm wondering, how this value can be used for updating the chart, when the user manually change the zoom level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **xAxis.update** feature to set a calculated value. See:

```
  xAxis: {
    overscroll: (1 * 60 * 1000) / 2, // default range is 1m, so default overscroll is 1m / 2
         events: {
          afterSetExtremes: function() {
            var value = getOverscroll(this.chart)   
            this.update({
                overscroll: value
            })
          }
        } 
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/24vgr1eb/
API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update

Is that what you have had in mind?

Comment: Why using `getOverscroll()` if you can get `min` and `max` from `event` argument passed to `afterSetExtremes`? See https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.AxisSetExtremesEventCallbackFunction